# Generating substrings in clojure

Tags: for-loop, clojure, substring

I am trying to generate all the possible prefix substrings of a given string in clojure. For example, if the word is `Ninja`, I want the output to be `("N" "Ni" "Nin" "Ninj" "Ninja")`

I can easily do that with this:

```
user=> (def a "Ninja")

user => (for [x (range 1 (+ 1 (.length a)))]
          (subs a 0 x))

("N" "Ni" "Nin" "Ninj" "Ninja")
```

And this is all fine... except.. I am using a for loop in there.. and it doesn't look very clojure-y.. is there a better / proper way to do this without the for loop or is the for loop completely okay in this case?

thank you

Comment: to be clear, `for` in Clojure is not a for loop, it is a list comprehension

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mapping `subs` over the length as in your `for` comprehension or [with map explicitly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22943000/1756702) is what I'd do as well.

However, if you *really* want a higher level function, you could use `reductions`

```
(rest (reductions str (str) "Ninja"))
;=> ("N" "Ni" "Nin" "Ninj" "Ninja")
```

If you had wanted suffixes instead, you could do so nicely with `iterate` and `subs` since you wouldn't have to specify the end.

```
(take-while seq (iterate #(subs % 1) "Ninja"))
;=> ("Ninja" "inja" "nja" "ja" "a")
```

Comment: didn't know about that function - http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/reductions

Comment: reductions is pretty cool, thanks! Also thanks for comments about `for`, I think, for the reader, it may be a lot more obvious as to what it's doing than reductions.

Answer (score 4):

`for` comprehensions are perfectly fine, IMO. If you'd like to see another approach, here is what I would do:

```
(map (partial subs a 0) (range 1 (-> a count inc)))
;; ("N" "Ni" "Nin" "Ninj" "Ninja")
```

Comment: Instead of the `(repeat a)`, just place `a` as the first argument to `subs`.

Comment: @A.Webb nice suggestion. Now it's pretty much your answer :)

Comment: Yeah, which is why I deleted mine :).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `reduce`

```
user=> (reduce #(conj % (str (first %) %2)) '() "Ninja")
("Ninja" "Ninj" "Nin" "Ni" "N")
```